# Hide Network drive from command line or VB Script

Tags: c#, windows, command-line, vbscript

We have a situation where we want to hide network drive suppose "L:"
Can this be achieved through command line or VBScript or C#

Comment: Did you try anything? Some code example would be nice..

Comment: No I have no idea how to achieve this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to modify the "NoDrive" key in the registry.

This article explains it:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/hide-drives-from-your-computer-in-windows-vista/